# How to autocomplete a combobox in a winforms app

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I thought I'd add a small class, something like:

```
Public NotInheritable Class TextListener
    Private captured As String
    Private ReadOnly stopwatch As New Stopwatch()
    Private ReadOnly timeout As Integer
    Private ReadOnly values As SortedSet(Of String)

    Public Sub New(ByVal timeout As Integer, ByVal comboBox As ComboBox)
        comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        comboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
        comboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None
        comboBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Nothing
        Me.timeout = timeout
        Me.values = New SortedSet(Of String)()
        For Each item In comboBox.Items
            values.Add(item.ToString())
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub notify(ByVal entered As String)
        If stopwatch.IsRunning _
        AndAlso stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < timeout Then
            captured &= entered
        Else
            captured = entered
        End If
        stopwatch.Restart()
    End Sub

    Public Function Index() As Integer
        Dim added As Boolean = values.Add(captured)
        Dim toreturn As Integer = Array.IndexOf(values.ToArray, captured)
        If added Then
            values.Remove(captured)
        End If
        toreturn = Math.Max(toreturn, 0)
        toreturn = Math.Min(toreturn, values.Count - 1)
        Return toreturn
    End Function
End Class
```

In short: it builds a string and finds where that goes in the combobox. (Assume the combobox is sorted and contains strings.) `Index()` returns where the String that was built would go in the index. (PS, I know sorted set isn't the most efficient way to do this, that there are other considerations with the combobox's values, but for now I'm just hashing out ideas and I can change implementation later.)

So, the idea is as someone types in the combobox, it completes what they have written, but resets that after a certain amount of time. Example implementation:

```
Public Class SomeForm

    Private ReadOnly listener As TextListener

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        listener = New TextListener(500, ComboBoxObj)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBoxObj_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComboBoxObj.KeyPress
        listener.notify(e.KeyChar)
        ComboBoxObj.SelectedIndex = listener.Index()
    End Sub

End Class
```

From debugging, I found that it's building the Strings correctly and returning the correct index, but it's behaving the ordinary way, where, let's say this is a list of states, pressing "M" gets you to "Maine", but then "a" gets you to "Alabama", even though it's returning an index of 18, and our listener object's `captured` field's value is `"Ma"`.

(Note: I posted this with the line `ComboBoxObj.SelectedItem = listener.Index()`, but this was a mistake. I tried changing `Index()` to return an `Object`, and missed changing it back to what I had before when posting.)

What am I missing here?

Comment: I am not sure that is going to work.  It *sounds like* you are trying to position the selected item in the dropdown list.  That is not what SelectedIndex does - it sets the selected item for the CBO not the DDL

Comment: I'm trying to select the item for the user. E.g. typing in "Mai" should select "Maine". If I type "Mai" wait about a second, then start typing "Pen" it should select "Pennsylvania".

Comment: sounds like what `AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems` and `AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest` (or maybe SuggestAppend) does - positions the DDL to the most likely candidate for what is typed so far